# Quantlib FRA and interpolated rate in Swaps vs BBG valuation

Tags: interest-rates, quantlib, swaps, pricing

I am building a CZK swap pricer on quantlib, and I am trying to understand my differences with Bloomberg pricing.

I believe the way I set up my FRA is wrong, the reason is because even though I match perfectly Bloomberg's pay leg after the FRA periods, I don't match bloomberg at all on one date that should be interpolated by FRA pricing,

Here is an example, I am trying to price a 1m forward 10 year maturity CZK swap, as of 31/01/2023. Both bloomberg and quantlib match on each payment date - **except one on 04/03/2023**. It's interesting because when I checked, the difference is indeed in the reset rate value (6.54753% for BBG and 6.02% for quantlib), which is relatively big

this is my raw curve data

[image]

See below my code with the curve, (I changed it slightly so it's more readable). Mapping below

```
'CZK': {
    'ql_index' : ql.IborIndex('PRIBOR6M',ql.Period('6M'),2,ql.CZKCurrency(),ql.CzechRepublic(),ql.ModifiedFollowing,False,
                              ql.Actual360()),
    'ql_settle_days' : 2,
    'ql_swap_calendar' : ql.CzechRepublic(),
    'ql_payment_convention_floating' : ql.ModifiedFollowing,
    'ql_payment_convention_fixed' : ql.ModifiedFollowing,
    'ql_currency' : ql.CZKCurrency(),
    'ql_payment_lag' : 0,
    'ql_payment_frequency_floating' : ql.Semiannual,
    'ql_payment_frequency_fixed' : ql.Annual,
    'ql_daycount_float' : ql.Actual360(),
    'ql_daycount_fixed' : ql.Actual360(),
    'ql_fixed_tenor' : ql.Period('1Y'),
```

and code here

```
df_mapping = 'get table above'

helpers = []


for index,row in df_mapping.iterrows():
    if row['Type'] == 'Depo':
        rate_ql = ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(row[date_str]/100))
        helpers.append(ql.DepositRateHelper(rate_ql,index_ql))
    elif row['Type'] == 'FRA':
        month_to_start = row['FRAstart']
        month_end = row['FRAend']
        rate_ql = ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(row[date_str]/100))
        helpers.append(ql.FraRateHelper(rate_ql,int(month_to_start),index_ql))
    elif row['Type'] == 'swap':
        tenor = row['Tenor']
        rate_ql = ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(row[date_str]/100))
        helpers.append(ql.SwapRateHelper(rate_ql,ql.Period(tenor),calendar_ql,fixed_paymentFrequency_ql,paymentconvention_ql_fixed,fixed_daycount_ql,index_ql))

curve_ql = ql.PiecewiseLogLinearDiscount(date_ql,helpers,fixed_daycount_ql)
```

I then create engine / price swap with makevanillaswap func

```
yts = ql.RelinkableYieldTermStructureHandle(curve_ql)
index_ql = index_ql.clone(yts)
engine = ql.DiscountingSwapEngine(yts)
fixed_tenor = param.dict_curve_conv[curve]['ql_fixed_tenor']
new_swap = ql.MakeVanillaSwap(ql.Period('10Y'), index_ql, 0.0435, ql.Period('1M'), swapType=ql.VanillaSwap.Receiver,pricingEngine=engine,
                           Nominal=10e6,fixedLegTenor=fixed_tenor,fixedLegDayCount=fixed_daycount_ql)
```

Looking at pay leg cashflow table I see everything matches but one row ...

this is quantlib

[image: quantlib payleg cashflow table]

and this is bloomberg

[image]

Very curious to hear your thoughts on this, note that I believe it is because of FRAs because I don't have this issue for curves without FRA interpolation.

Thanks again for your help, and obviously happy to answer any questions

Comment: I see many values in the same column are also different from Bloomberg. Would you explain those as well?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what are your Bloomberg setting for the CZK, but I'm pretty sure it has to do with interpolation method.

The slope between the two nodes for determining the forward you mention is considerable, and you can try different interpolation methods to see the differences.

```
ryts = ql.RelinkableYieldTermStructureHandle()
index = index.clone(ryts)
engine = ql.DiscountingSwapEngine(ryts)

new_swap = ql.MakeVanillaSwap(
    ql.Period('10Y'),
    index, 
    0.0435, 
    ql.Period('1M'), 
    swapType=ql.VanillaSwap.Receiver,
    pricingEngine=engine,
    Nominal=10e6,
    fixedLegTenor=ql.Period('1Y'),
    fixedLegDayCount=ql.Actual360()
)

piecewiseMethods = {
    'logLinearDiscount': ql.PiecewiseLogLinearDiscount,
    'logCubicDiscount': ql.PiecewiseLogCubicDiscount,
    'linearZero': ql.PiecewiseLinearZero,
    'cubicZero': ql.PiecewiseCubicZero,
    'linearForward': ql.PiecewiseLinearForward,
    'splineCubicDiscount': ql.PiecewiseSplineCubicDiscount,
}

for name, piecewise in piecewiseMethods.items():
    crv = piecewise(2, calendar, helpers, ql.Actual365Fixed())
    ryts.linkTo(crv)

    floating_cashflows = list(map(ql.as_floating_rate_coupon, new_swap.floatingLeg()))
    fwd = floating_cashflows[1].rate()
    amount = floating_cashflows[1].amount()
    print(f"{name:>20}\t{fwd:.3%}\t{amount:,.2f}")
```

[image]

As you might know, the particular interpolation method you use can greatly influence the behavior of the forwards between your data points.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 3, figsize=(8,4), sharey=True, sharex=True)
ax = ax.flatten()
dates = [ql.Date(4,3,2023) + ql.Period(n, ql.Days) for n in range(360)]
start_dates = dates[:180]
end_dates = dates[-180:]

dc = ql.Actual360()
for idx, (name, piecewise) in enumerate(piecewiseMethods.items()):
    crv = piecewise(2, calendar, helpers, ql.Actual365Fixed())
    ryts.linkTo(crv)
    rates = [crv.forwardRate(start, end, dc, ql.Simple).rate() for start, end in zip(start_dates, end_dates)]
    ax[idx].plot(rates)
    ax[idx].set_title(name)
    ax[idx].scatter([0,180], [rates[0], rates[179]])
```

[image]

Comment: Very insightful and helpful as always.